# Java changing method return without access to the class Class

Tags: java

I'm modifying someone else's code to implement a new functionality and I can't do it without changing the return of one of the functions. As I've said, this is not my code, so I can't change a single line of code.

The function itself is the following:

```
package me.Mohamad82.MineableGems.Core;

public class DropReader {
  ...
  public DropReader() {}
  public CustomDrop readCustomDrop(ConfigurationSection section, String mined, @Nullable String sectionNumber) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to do something like this:

```
package com.rogermiranda1000.mineit;

public class DropReader extends me.Mohamad82.MineableGems.Core.DropReader {
    public DropReader() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomDrop readCustomDrop(ConfigurationSection section, String mined, @Nullable String sectionNumber) {
        CustomDrop drop = super.readCustomDrop(section, mined, sectionNumber);
        if (drop != null) {...}
        return drop;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea where to start. I can't change their code to call the other object, and I can't change the function call either.

The object is created every time (inside the functions that uses DropReader) so Reflection won't work, and searching I found something named Javassist but it won't work if the class is already loaded. I should be able to load by code before, but even with that I don't know if I'm approaching to the problem correctly, what do you think?

Edit: I'll try to explain better the situation. There's a class named **Commands** that runs the command `new DropReader().readCustomDrop(section, mined, sectionNumber)`. The problem is that **if `section.getString("mine") != null` I need to change the `readCustomDrop` return** (I need to add an aditional property).

**I can't change Commands's code, nor DropReader. Commands MUST get the modified object.**

Edit2: It should work on both Java 8 and 17.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly, but can't you just write a wrapper around an instance of that class?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the object instances are inside the class that I can't modify

Comment: Why you can not change the code? Is it a library? A .class file?

Comment: More or less? If you have the source code right in your project source code, change it, don't be afraid. I don't understand why you think you can't do it.

Comment: What’s wrong with the object normally returned by readCustomDrop?

Comment: @CaptainPyscho it's a Minecraft Plugin, I'm modifying it just a little to make it compatible with mine, I can't upload it entirely just changing 3 lines of code

Comment: @VGR I need to add a property to the returned object if one of the arguments meets some requirements

Comment: So create your own subclass of CustomDrop with that additional property, and copy the properties of the other CustomDrop into an instance of your subclass.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I can't because I can't modify the code

Comment: Why do you need to modify that code?  *Read* from the object returned by that code, and create a *new, different* object which you yourself can modify and return in your method override.

Comment: I have updated the description. If I could run some code when the object it's returned I could do that, but I don't know when the object will be changed (so, I don't know where to modify the object and change it to the new one).

Comment: Thank you for the updates.  I am starting to understand the problem better.  Why do you need a different object to be used internally by Commands?  Is that object passed back to your code somehow?

Comment: That's exactly what happens. The change it's invisible for the other's class, but once I read the object I can check if it's one of mines and get that extra property.

Comment: @user16320675 your solution is the closest right now, but I don't know how to change an `execution` (it won't work with `call`) of an external, unloaded, library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is Java Instrumentation, but it was too complex for me so I did the following (assuming you have the .jar, and the .jar it's not already loaded):

1. Open the .jar as a Zip using ZipFile class
2. Send the .java to ClassFileToJavaSourceDecompiler (from [JD-Core](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-core)) and decompile it
3. Change the .java code
4. Compile the new code running `javac` with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` (note: you'll probably need to add the dependencies using `-classpath`)
5. Add the compiled .java to the .jar